# How to send optional parameters in retrofit2?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I am using retrofit to send calls to my own api, and in the section of editting person profile, the user maybe doesn't want to modify every single information about him, so I want to send parameters as optional so in my api when the parameter is empty I want not to modify it in the database.
anyone tried to do that? how?
THANKS FOR ALL.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial on optional query parameters:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-optional-query-parameters

The short answer is that you can simply pass `null` as a parameter when you don't want to pass a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@FieldMap`:

```
... things(@FieldMap Map<String, Object> params);
```

Create a `HashMap<String, Object>` and add all your dynamic params into it and pass the `HashMap` to the `FieldMap` params.